# what does this sed expr. match actually? s/^.*EngineLog ERROR://

Tags: regex, sed

sed Expression 's/^.*EngineLog ERROR://'

Comment: You're asking a question because something is not as you expected.  Can you tell us what problem you've encountered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It matches anything that starts 0 or more characters then EngineLog ERROR: and then replaces it with nothing

Example all output the same: **EngineLog ERROR:** 
:

`1EngineLog ERROR:`
`1 EngineLog ERROR:`  
`EngineLog ERROR:`